# Regular Expression confusion

Tags: c#, regex

I want to check a name using regular expression, but I'm not getting convincing result. Could anyone please suggest what wrong I'm doing in my regular expression pattern?

```
foreach(Match m in
(Regex.Matches("Jack_Sparrow","^[A-za-z]+[^-]*(\\d)*$")))
     { 
      Console.WriteLine("{0} found at index{1}",m.Value,m.Index);
     }
```

May I know why I'm getting **Jack_Sparrow** as output, despite of not checking underscore(_) in the patter? I rather want **Jack Sparrow** as an output. What's modification I need?

Comment: sounds like what you *need* is to do a `str_replace("_", " ", $username)`. But unless you describe your problem a little better or give a few more examples, no one can really know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first half of your character range is including it.

`[A-za-z]` creates a range from upper case A to lower case z, then another range from lower case a to lower case z. These ranges overlap in their second portion because of the way the ASCII values work out. Specifically, `A-z` creates a range from ASCII character 65 (A) to character 122 (z). The underscore character has a value of 95, which is in between. Since your regex is anchored, this character class [is where the match is occurring](http://rubular.com/r/CnPO0W1xao). I've changed your character class to include grouping parentheses in this example so that you can see it is capturing the entire text of "Jack_Sparrow".

You should be able to solve this specific match by changing the character range to be `[A-Za-z]` instead. It will, however,  still match the first portion ("Jack") and then the `[^-]*` portion will match the remainder of the string ("_Sparrow"), still causing it to be a valid match. If you can provide some other text examples, then we can help you refine this further, though. With the current information you've provided, it's difficult to tell how to best fix the `[^-]` issue.

Comment: Charles is still right that even if he fixes this, it will continue to match due to `[^-]`.

Comment: @Ralph: Yes, just noted that. I should have mentioned that previously.

Comment: Err.. not really. He ends his regex with `$`. It has to match to the end of the string, or it won't match at all. This will *not* match only "Jack".

Comment: @Ralph: I meant that the leading `[A-Za-z]+` will match only "Jack" and then the `[^-]*` will pick up everything after that. It would also match the string "Jack" by itself, though, if he only modified the initial character class.

Comment: any regex reference for becoming regex expert? it seems to me that regex is causing people headache, people just guessing and guessing or some would probably use already defined regex, I think not much people is expert? how to be one?

Comment: @John: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html The only people who are "guessing" are those who are too lazy to sit down and actually learn them. They look confusing at first, but they're really not that difficult.

Answer (score 1):

`[^-]` checks for any character other than -, so that's what matches the underscore.  I'm not sure exactly what you want to match here.

Are you trying to change everything other than letters to spaces, perhaps?

Comment: If I omit [^-], and then I'm getting "Jack_Sparrow" as an output. May I know why?

Answer (score 0):

foreach(Match m in
(Regex.Matches("Jack_Sparrow","[^A-Za-z ]"))
     { 
      Console.WriteLine("{0} found at index{1}",m.Value,m.Index);
     }